# CSS styles not being applied to view

Tags: css, node.js, express, pug

I'm creating an app with node.js and express. I'm using pug as my template engine. The styles from the stylesheet are not being applied to the view.

In my header.pug file I have

```
link(rel='stylesheets/style.css', type='text/css', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
```

The style sheet is located in public/stylesheets. I've also included the following code below in my app.js file.

```js
// serve static files from /public
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
```

When I run the application and expect the document I can open the stylesheet in the new tap and see the stylesheet, but it's not applying those styles to the pug file?

Answer (score 0):

remove first /

also change rel atribute

like:

```
    link(rel='stylesheet', type='text/css', href='stylesheets/style.css')
```

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't work either. I mean when I inspect the element I can see the style sheet(in a new tab) but for some reason it's not applying the styles. i.e. I'm doing the  background of the body to blue to test and I can see that rule when I inspect but it's not being applied.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this way to load stylesheet.

**index.pug**

```
html  
head
    style
        include style.css
    title This is my first Pug file 
body
    div.split.left
        div.centered...
```

Folder structure need to be like this.

```
views
   index.pug
   style.css
index.js
```